# Can't get a Counter() to work in python

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a counter which uses a list of POS trigrams to check to a large list of trigrams and find their frequency.
My code so far is as follows:

```
from nltk import trigrams
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk import bigrams
from collections import Counter
import nltk
text= ["This is an example sentence."]
trigram_top= ['PRP', 'MD', 'VB']

   for words in text:
      tokens = wordpunct_tokenize (words)
      tags = nltk.pos_tag (tokens)
      trigram_list=trigrams(tags)
      list_tri=Counter (t for t in trigram_list if t in trigram_top)
      print list_tri
```

I get an empty counter back. How do I mend this?
In an earlier version I did get data back, but it kept counting up for ever iteration (in the real program, text is a collection of different files).
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What does `[t for t in trigram_list if t in trigram_top]` give you? So, remove the `Counter`, make it a list.

Comment: that statement checks every trigram in text vs every trigram in trigram top. What do you mean, make it a list?

Comment: The expression I gave you is a list comprehension. It lets you test if you are giving *anything at all* to `Counter()`.

Comment: From looking at [the ntlk source](http://nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#trigrams), `trigrams()` returns a list of tuples.  This means that none of the elements in the result of `trigrams()` will be in `trigram_top` (which contains only strings), so you are passing an empty iterable to `Counter()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, it gives me back the following: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x05B59918>.

Comment: @Nikolaas: no, I used square brackets, not parenthesis. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Let's put some `print` in there to debug:

```
from nltk import trigrams
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk import bigrams
from collections import Counter
import nltk
text= ["This is an example sentence."]
trigram_top= ['PRP', 'MD', 'VB']

for words in text:
    tokens = wordpunct_tokenize (words)
    print tokens
    tags = nltk.pos_tag (tokens)
    print tags
    list_tri=Counter (t[0] for t in tags if t[1] in trigram_top)
    print list_tri

#['This', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'sentence', '.']
#[('This', 'DT'), ('is', 'VBZ'), ('an', 'DT'), ('example', 'NN'), ('sentence', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
#Counter()
```

Note that the `list=` part was redundant and I've changed the generator to just take the word instead of the pos tag

We can see that none of the pos tags directly match your trigram_top - you may want to amend your comparison check to cater for VB/VBZ...

A possibility would be changing the line:

```
list_tri=Counter (t[0] for t in tags if t[1].startswith(tuple(trigram_top)))
# Counter({'is': 1})
```

Comment: Next step: turn `trigram_top` into a set for efficient membership testing: `{'PRP', 'MD', 'VB'}`.

Comment: This script only checks for unigrams in the trigram list if I'm not mistaken, is there a way to only check of trigrams?

Comment: I want to see what sequences of tags are present in each instance of text. The sequences are represented in trigram top.

Comment: @Nikolaas so what would be the expected result for the above then?

Comment: well, the actual list has about 25 trigrams, a correct result would be the occurence of each trigram in each text, looking something like this: [23, 12, 34, 22, 23, 23, 12, 34, 22, 23,23, 12, 34, 22, 23,23, 12, 34, 22, 0].

Comment: Okay - I'll ask again - what would be the result for the example you've given above? :)

Comment: Since there is only one trigram in the example sentence, which isn't represented in the example sentence (the real text is much larger) the result here ought to be [0], but [1] if text was: "you should work".